# Networking issues on Thinkpad T480 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, suspend, thinkpad

I recently purchased a Thinkpad T480 and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Overall it works fine except for one issue. When I resume the laptop from sleep, I face networking related issues. It's not that internet does not work but I cannot access all the options like seeing which wifi network I am connected to, list of wifi networks available, switching to a different wifi network etc. Is there any fix available for this? The model I am using is a T480 with i7 processor.

Comment: I initially faced this problem. But this got solved gradually after few kernel updates. See if all updates have been installed and still problem persists.

Comment: @Jrct Installed all the updates and disabled wifi powersafe in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`. That solved it. Sometimes I still face issue but restarting `network-manager` solves it then. Earlier restarting `network-manager` also wasn't helping but now it works. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear. Post this as an Answer, might be helpful for someone else later..

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

Install all the updates using the software updater.

Then check the contents of the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`. By default it should be:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

3 here means wifi powersave is enabled. Change it to 2 (which means disabled). Reboot the computer. After I did this, it has been working fine for me most of the times. Sometimes when it doesn't, I restart the  `network-manager` service by running the following command in the terminal

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then it works fine. Hope this helps.